# Unspent account and additional wallet in a transaction

Tags: transactions

I just moved some BTC from one wallet to another.  As I investigated the TX ID, I'm confused by why there are other amounts that aren't what I sent.  In my case I sent .25 BTC, and there are 2 transactions showing up (1 for .25, and another for .7).  The other one says "unspent".

I'm wondering what's going on here, and if there is a simple explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably this is your wallet software doing for you. It might be, that your wallet only had one output to spend from, with .95 bitcoin. And you wanted to send only .25. So the wallet had to divide it somehow... it created a transaction with two outputs, one of which is the return address. Probably this address is also in your wallet. Check the addresses in the wallet, to see if it belongs to you. Or check the remaining balance. If there, then all ok. If not, there is a need for further investigation, but this would require more info...